# Azure service call to server under firewall

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure app service.
I want to call to a private(under firewall) service from the app service and receive a response.

What to set on private service's firewall to ba able to call from app service and get response?

Comment: Your app service should be able to reach your private service. For that Firewall must be configured to allow inbound connections to the port on which your private service is listening.

Answer (score 2):

On Azure Web App properties panel, you could get a list of outbound IP addresses. To enable your app service to call your private service, you need to configure these IP addresses to the inbound security of private service's firewall.

[image]

Please note that only app service hosted in App Service Environment has a static outbound IP address. For other app services, the outbound IP addresses may be changed due to following reasons. We need to change the inbound security of private service's firewall if the outbound IP addresses are changed.

1. It becomes necessary for Azure infrastructure to increase the number of outbound IP addresses. In that case the existing IP addresses will be preserved but there will be some new ones. So far there hasn't been a need to increase number of IP addresses and if there ever be the need for that there will be an early notice about it.
2. The Web App gets relocated to a different scale unit. Prior to that the subscription owner gets an email notification one month in advance.

Comment: Any update? Have you tried my suggestion? If you have further questions about this topic, please feel free to let me know.